# Parse error on input 'if' when trying to use a condition inside a do block

Tags: haskell

I have the following code and I already tried multiple ways to write this, but I can't make it work. What I need is to use an `if` condition inside a `do` block.

```
palin :: IO ()
palin 
  = do line <- getLine
       putStr line
       if True
         then putStr line
```

I changed the condition to true just to make it easier. I tried adding the `else` sentence, but I get the same.

Comment: If you don't want to do anything in the else, then you should use `when `.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Haskell, an if-else expression does not mean "if true, execute foo; else, execute bar", but "if true, the value is foo; else, the value is bar". For that reason, you can't omit the `else`, much in the same way that you can't when using the ternary if operator (`conditon ? foo : bar`)  in other languages. In your case, the `then` part is a value of type `IO ()`, so you need an `else` with the same type. As you do not want antyhing to actually happen if the condition is false, the most immediate solution is using the dummy `IO ()` value, `return ()`:

```
palin :: IO ()
palin 
  = do line <- getLine
       putStr line
       if True
         then putStr line
         else return ()
```

You can also use the `when` function from `Control.Monad`, which has the same effect:

```
import Control.Monad

palin :: IO ()
palin 
  = do line <- getLine
       putStr line
       when True (putStr line)
```

Comment: Thank you! perfect explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an else.

```
palin :: IO ()
palin = do
  line <- getLine
  putStr line --Probably better to use putStrLn?
  if True then putStr line else putStr "hi" --Also consider putStrLn here?
```

You need to provide an value, if you're coming from Python, then think about something like

`a = "dogs" if 1 < 0 else "cats"`
here, you need to provide the else as without it the variable assignment wouldn't run.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell everything after `=` is an expression, and expressions usually have values. Even conditional statement is expression as well as `putStr "hi"` and they have their (return) values. In case of `if` return value is value of corresponding branch (then or else). In case of `putStr "hi"` it's somewhat more involved, I won't explain it here (see IO and monads)

So the correct way to write your code would be the following:

```
palin :: IO ()
palin = do line <- getLine
           if True
             then putStr line
             else return ()
             -- this return has nothing to do with return in python
             -- basically it means "do nothing"
```