# Assigning special cases when certain variables have certain values?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

for my functional programming homework I am instructed to write a function that gives back the real solutions of a quadratic equation in a list, I used the discriminant to find them out.

So, my code looks something like this:

```
quadSols::Double->Double->Double->[Double]
quadSols a b c = [x1,x2]
      where
          x1 = (-b - sqrt d) / (2 * a)
          x2 = (-b + sqrt d) / (2 * a)
          d = (b * b) - 4 * a * c
```

Now, the problem is in the case a = 0, for which the solution would be simply x = -c / b.
I tried something like this, it sounds completely wrong but I don't really know what to do.

```
if a == 0 then quadSols a b c = [x]
```

and then added to the "where" part:

```
x = -c / b
```

when trying to load it with ghci I get:

```
parse error on input ‘=’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Can anyone provide me with some guidance?

Comment: "I haven't been able to formulate this case without getting syntax errors." -- Which errors, and how you got to them? Please edit that into your question. (A question which tells the full story leads to less work for everyone and to better answers.)

Comment: Please post the _full_ code you've tried, and the full error message it caused.

Comment: Something not directly related to the immediate problem: what is supposed to happen if the discriminant is negative?

Comment: I was thinking of asking about that here as well, but figured that if I could find out the a = 0 problem then perhaps I'll be able to figure out the negative case by myself. I was thinking of it just returning an empty list or display an error message: Not possible in R.

Comment: @Rad Returning an empty list is fine. If your function is supposed to give back "the real solution**s**" and does that through a list, returning an empty list if there are no solutions is reasonable and unsurprising.

Comment: @duplode Sorry, could you please show me the technicalities of it? I tried:

    quadSols::Double->Double->Double->[Double]
    quadSols a b c = [x1,x2]
        where
          x1 = (-b - sqrt d) / (2 * a)
          x2 = (-b + sqrt d) / (2 * a)
          d = (b * b) - 4 * a * c
      if d < 0 then quadSols a b c = []
      else quadSols a b c = [x] || [x1,x2]

I get: Prelude> :load a.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( a.hs, interpreted )

a.hs:9:12 parse error on input ‘if’
Failed, modules loaded: none   Perhaps something is wrong with the indentation or is my logic wrong?

Comment: Oops, that format looks messed up in the comment. I hope you are able to understand it.

Comment: @Rad If I am not misunderstanding the non-formatted code, the problem is that `if ... then ... else` is just a normal expression, and should go as a whole after the equals sign (something like `foo = if bar then baz else quux`). If you are familiar with ternary operators in other languages, it works very much like them. In any case, the second implementation in Jon Purdy's answer provides a nice model for fixing your code.

Comment: @Rad [What I have just said about `if` in a less compressed way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23463132/2751851) (feel free to ignore the code around the if-then-else if it confuses you).

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it by managing the whole thing in guards. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pattern match for the case where `a == 0`:

```
quadSols :: Double -> Double-> Double-> [Double]
quadSols 0 b c = [x]
      where x = -c / b
quadSols a b c = [x1,x2]
      where
          x1 = (-b - sqrt d) / (2 * a)
          x2 = (-b + sqrt d) / (2 * a)
          d = (b * b) - 4 * a * c
```

Note that you **must** include the first case before the second, since cases are matched in the order they are declared.

Comment: Thank you! I will take note of this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another equation to `quadSols`:

```
quadSols 0 b c = [x]
  where
    x = (-c) / b

quadSols a b c = [x1,x2]
  where
    …
```

Or use a guard:

```
quadSols a b c
  | a == 0 = [x]
  | otherwise = [x1,x2]
  where
    x = (-c) / b
    …
```

Due to laziness, the definitions in the `where` clause won’t be evaluated unless necessary to produce a result.